# creating shortcuts in drupal 7.17

Tags: drupal-7

In drupal 7.17 I copy this url #overlay=%3Fq%3Dadmin%252Fmodules then click Edit, Shortcuts then Add Shortcut I past it in and get this error:
  The link must correspond to a valid path on the site.
In the tutorial I'm taking it makes a new shortcut
the url in this case is from the modules page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The shortcut should be `admin/modules` - the `#overlay` part will be added on automatically when the admin overlay is enabled.